# How to use ObjectBox in Gradle multi-module project?

Tags: android, multi-module, objectbox

I try to create multi-module project with two features(**A** and **B**). They have several entities **AEntity** and **BEntity**.

After make project I have several **MyObjectBox** classes in the each feature-module.

When I do:

```
FeatureA.MyObjectBox.builder()
                .androidContext(application)
                .build()

FeatureB.MyObjectBox.builder()
                    .androidContext(application)
                    .build()
```

I catch this: Another BoxStore is still open for this directory...
Cause BoxStore can be opened only one time for one directory.

How I can create BoxStores for multi-module project if my models stored in several gradle feature-modules?

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

To do this you can create two BoxStore`s but you must set name in BoxStoreBuilder:

```
FeatureA.MyObjectBox.builder()
                .androidContext(application)
                .name("FeatureA")
                .build()

FeatureB.MyObjectBox.builder()
                .androidContext(application)
                .name("FeatureB")
                .build()
```

But there is one limitation. You can not create relations between AEntity and BEntity...